# How to save EditText text while staying on the same activity and be able to use it after

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-edittext

I am trying to figure out how to save the contents of two `EditText`, but the example on the official website does this while simultaneously *changing the Activity* and displaying it.

I want to save the `EditText` contents *without changing the Activity*, and then be able to display them when the *Activity changes*.

I feel like the problem might be that I am not understanding how Intents really work

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
    EditText editPositive = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPositive);
    EditText editNegative = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editNegative);
    editPositive.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = null;
            EditText editPositive = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPositive);
            String positive = editPositive.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra(POSITIVE_MESSAGE, positive);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }); `
```

now I am trying to save this editText's contents to be usable by any view, but in the example on the developer website, they already know the view they will use the editText on, it doesn't  show you how to be able to use it on any view.  Instead of

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
```

I don't know which out of the views for each of the 365 days of the year I will use the editText's contents on.  It depends on what date the user enters in the datePicker that pops up.  How would I write an intent that I can use from any view? and I'm guessing that this method does not go in the on create but that is the only place that I didn't get an error when I placed it.

Comment: @user1741292 Please give more information so we can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

Use `onTextChangedListener` and save the editText value as soon as entered.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //intent to another page where i show my search result
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please let me know what more information I need to enter to make this my updated question answerable.

Comment: above is the answer for your question. Don't keep updating the Question. Moreover i didt understand the question clearly.